# Scraping images from user input URL using MetaInspector (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, screen-scraping

I'm trying to create an app where a user can submit a URL link, a title and description, and it'll create a post with the title, description and an image. I want to be able to scrape the best or main image from directly from the URL path that the user submitted and display it on the show page using [MetaInspector](https://github.com/jaimeiniesta/metainspector). (The reason I didn't use Nokogiri or Mechanize is because I didn't understand it all that well and MetaInspector seems alot less daunting)

The problem is I'm very new to rails and I'm having a hard time following most tutorials.

Is anyone able to explain to me step by step how to do this or show me a source that's very detailed and noob friendly?

I have a [`Post`](https://github.com/johnnyji/wanderful/blob/master/app/models/post.rb) model that contains the link, and should also save the scraped image as a `Paperclip` attachment:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :image
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: posts
#
# id                  :integer          not null, primary key
# title               :string
# link                :string
# description         :text
# created_at          :datetime
# updated_at          :datetime
# user_id             :integer
# image_file_name     :string
# image_content_type  :string
# image_file_size     :integer
# image_updated_at    :datetime
```

The full code of my app is available at [github.com/johnnyji/wanderful](https://github.com/johnnyji/wanderful).

I really appreciate any help at all! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's walk through this step by step.

First, add the MetaInspector gem to your Gemfile

```
gem 'metainspector'
```

and run the `bundle` command.

We need another bit of code: [`open-uri`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html). With it, we can read remote files from URLs as if they were local files. It is part of Rubys standard library, so it's already built in, but we still need to `require` it at the top of your post.rb:

```
require 'open-uri'

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :image
end
```

We want to grab an image whenever a Posts `link` changes, so we make a `before_save` callback that triggers whenever that happens:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :image

  before_save :get_image_from_link,
              if: ->(post) { post.link_changed? }

end
```

- you can find more about `before_save` and other callbacks in the [ActiveRecord::Callbacks guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html).
- the `link_changed?` method is part of the "dirty tracking" functionality [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) provides
- that `if: ->(post)` thing is called a "stabby lambda" - it's basically just a Ruby function that is called with the current `post` as an argument. If it returns `true`, the `before_action` is run. It could also be written as `if: Proc.new { |post| post.link_changed? }`

Now we need our `get_image_from_link` method. Since it's only supposed to be called from within the `Post` model itself and not from the outside (say, `Post.find(5).get_image_from_link`), we make it a private method:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :image

  before_save :get_image_from_link,
              if: ->(post) { post.link_changed? }

    private

  def get_image_from_link
  end
end
```

Reading MetaInspectors README, it has a cool method called `page.images.best` that does the hard work for us selecting the right image from that page. So we are going to

1. parse the link with MetaInspector
2. open the image it selected as best with `open-uri` as a `File`-like object
3. give that `File`-like object to `Paperclip` to save as an attachment

So:

```
def get_image_from_link
  # `link` here is `self.link` = the current post.
  # At least when reading attributes, `self` is implicit
  # in Ruby
  page = MetaInspector.new(link)

  # maybe the page didn't have images?
  return unless page.images.best.present?

  # when you use IO resources such as files, you need
  # to take care that you `.close` everything you open.
  # Using the block form takes care of that automatically.
  open(page.images.best) do |file|

    # when writing/assigning a value, `self` is not
    # implicit, because when you write `something = 5`, 
    # Ruby cannot know whether you want to assign to 
    # `self.something` or create a new local variable 
    # called `something`
    self.image = file
  end
end
```

This is far from perfect, because it lacks some error handling (what if MetaInspector fails to open the page? Or open-uri cannot read the image URL?). Also, this has the drawback that all that parsing, downloading and so on takes place right when the user submits or updates her post, so when she clicks on the save button, she'll have to wait for all this to complete.

For the next iteration, look into doing things like these asynchronously, for example with a job queue. Rails' new [Active Job](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) system might be a good starting point.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for explaining where to begin. I always get so lost because I see the code snippets in tutorials but I never know where to put them in my rails files. So once I've implemented this code in my files, what am I suppose to do in my posts/show.html.erb in order to display the scraped picture? I currently have `<%= image_tag @post.image.url(:medium) %>` which shows the images uploaded by the user using Paperclip

Comment: UPDATE: I've figured it out, thank you again good sir :) I'll definitely look into how to implement AJAX into this next!

Comment: Glad it worked! If you are happy with this answer, please mark it as "accepted", so that your question no longer shows up as unanswered to others.